# How do I rewrite this ES6 code to be Safari-compatible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some Vue.js code that uses ES6 arrow functions. However, apparently Safari (and it appears Chrome on OSX in one case) doesn't like this. Here's the code:

```
fetchItemCount: function(){
                this.$http.get('/api/fetchItemCount')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.itemCount = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(response => {

                    });
            },
```

I have several functions that use the arrow syntax. How can I rewrite them to avoid using it but still perform the same work?

I have tried using Babel to transpile the code but that seems to introduce errors (Unable to set property 'Vue' of undefined or null reference)

Comment: you can use https://babeljs.io/ to transpile your code into ES5

Comment: The next version of Safari (10) will also support arrow functions and all the other parts of ES6 for that matter. However, older browsers will still need ES5 code, which can be transpiled using a transpiler such as babel (mentioned in the comment above).

Comment: Please see my edit - I have tried using Babel but it introduces errors.

Comment: What errors  did you get ?

Comment: @OskarSzura I've added it to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted using a transpiler such as babel would do the trick but since that isn't always possible here is how it would look without arrow functions.

```
fetchItemCount: function(){
    var that = this;
    this.$http.get('/api/fetchItemCount')
        .then(function(response) {
            that.itemCount = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(response) {

        });
},
```

What the arrow function gives you is essentially a function that keeps the `this` scope of where it's declared, so to reproduce that we just need to assign `this` in the outer scope to a new variable and use that inside the function.

As LinusBorg noted in the comments, when using [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) you don't have to do the `var that = this;` part since the library will change `this` in the callback to the outer scope for you. This is specific to [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) resource though and not how it's generally done with promises so it generally won't work with other libraries.

Comment: While your explanation is generally correct, the `that = this` closure is unnessessary when using vue-resource, because it binds the callback function to the vm's scope for you.

Comment: Good to know, though I'll keep my answer the way it is since it isn't the normal behaviour of promises to bind to the outer context. I'll make a note of it though!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to rewrite your code, at least not manually. What you can do is keep writing code like the example you gave and use a transpiler, like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), to rewrite your ES6 code to ES5.

You can make it almost transparent to yourself by using a task manager like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

If you need to understand how to use a task manager, take a look at [this  article](https://blog.tecsinapse.com.br/using-gulp-to-speed-up-web-development-25c7187ca33a#.baa9zytu0). It gives you a short and focused overview on how to use Gulp.

After reading it you will see how easy is to automatically watch files and streamline their content through some Gulp script. So just use [Gulp Babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel) to do this transpile task automatically for you.

For example:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('transpile', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/MY-VUE-SOURCE.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('SOME_DESTINATION'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['src/**/*'], ['transpile']);
});
```

After running gulp watch, which is kept running until you manually stop it, any change that you make to MY-VUE-SOURCE.js will be automatically transpiled for you.

Comment: I do use Gulp and attempted to use Bower. However, when I switched to using the Babelified code, I started getting an error, which was occurring right at the start of the Vue.js library code: `Unable to set property 'Vue' of undefined or null reference`. This was using the ES2015 Babel preset.